# Object variable or With Block Variable Not set and data not going into right columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have two issues and was not sure to post two thread as I did not want to be called up for double posting. I have been trying to fix them for a few weeks now but just can not get my head around them. I am new to VBA and have very limited knowledge.

The code runs for a bit and then crashes and I get the first Error message, this error can highlight any part of the code, so I was not sure which to post.
   **1ST =  "Object variable or With Block Variable Not set" and code**

The 2nd is that I can not get the prices into the right columns, it is skipping some prices and also placing data in .  I have attached a URl for the file [Download](https://app.box.com/s/hkv6obkawnel3dxw6cj56h4jihxq9rkt)

```
Private Sub EbaySearch_Click()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").value & Replace(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").value, " ", "+")
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim doc As HTMLDocument
        Set doc = ie.Document
        While ie.readyState <> 4
        Wend
        Do
            Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To 500
                Range("A3").Offset(i).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("vip")(i).href ' URL
                Range("A3").Offset(i, 1).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("lvtitle")(i).innerText ' TITLE
                Range("A3").Offset(i, 2).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("hotness-signal red")(i).innerText ' SOLD AMOUNT
                Range("A3").Offset(i, 3).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("prRange")(i).innerText 'CURRENT PRICE
                Range("A3").Offset(i, 4).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("stk-thr")(i).innerText ' SHIPPING TYPE E.G FREE bfsp
                Range("A3").Offset(i, 5).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("bfsp")(i).innerText ' SHIPPING TYPE E.G FREE
                Range("A3").Offset(i, 6).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("lvsubtitle")(i).innerText 'SUB TITLE
                Range("A3").Offset(i, 7).value = doc.getElementsByClassName("FnFl fnf-green")(i).innerText
            Next i
            If PageNumber >= 2 Then Exit Do      ' Searches First two pages on Ebay
            Set nextPageElement = htmlDoc.getElementsByClassName("gspr next")(0)
            If nextPageElement Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            nextPageElement.Click                'Clicks Next Page
            Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Loop
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
            Set htmlDoc = ie.Document
            PageNumber = PageNumber + 1
        Loop
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
        Set htmlDoc = Nothing
        Set nextPageElement = Nothing
        Set div = Nothing
        Set link = Nothing
        MsgBox "All Done"
    End With
End Sub
```

I have declared the Variables now
`Dim ie As Object
Dim pageNumber As Long
Dim htmlDoc As Object
Dim nextPageElement As Object
Dim div As Object
Dim link As Object`

This is the error message, **Most of the prices in both columns DO NOT match the items.**
[image]

This is the error in the vba
[image]

Thanks for having a look, any guidance/support will do.
From what I can workout, there are several prices Buy now, Auction, Best offer and postage types etc. the code is doing three things wrong

1. It is putting the prices and postage types into the FIRST EMPTY CELL
   and not in the first blank row. so if there is NO item to input it
   should leave that cell blank for that product.
2. If the same class like "bfsp" is used for two or more elements then
   it puts both into the column e.g. cells D4 + D5 **e.g. Free Return
   and Free postage,** but I can not choose which one I want from the
   two I have tried `getElementsByClassName("bfsp")(i, 2).innerText`
   but it does not work to select the right one, I have tried an extra
   column but it pulls both again.
3. As there are are several prices, I have had to add more classes to
   the code to put this in to the next column, but again items are
   placed in the first blank cell and for class "bold" it is pulling up
   the wrong prices, it should be the auction prices but it is pulling
   up, current price and amount sold and placing them into one cell

`Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 500
    Range("A3").Offset(i).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("vip")(i).href ' URL
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 1).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("lvtitle")(i).innerText ' TITLE
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 2).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("hotness-signal red")(i).innerText ' SOLD AMOUNT
     Range("A3").Offset(i, 3).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("prRange")(i).innerText 'CURRENT PRICE
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 4).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("lvprice prc")(i).innerText 'Current Auction Price
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 5).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("stk-thr")(i).innerText ' SHIPPING TYPE E.G FREE
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 6).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("lvformat")(i).innerText ' Auction Bidds
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 7).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("bfsp")(i).innerText ' SHIPPING TYPE E.G FREE
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 8).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("fee")(i).innerText ' Auction Shipping
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 9).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("lvsubtitle")(i).innerText 'SUB TITLE
    Range("A3").Offset(i, 10).Value = doc.getElementsByClassName("FnFl fnf-green")(i).innerText
   Next i`

Sorry if this code does not look right, I am not use to this forum layout.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: It can be any line in the range, I thing the problem is that as it pulls of the prices, it does not put them in the right order, this is for the current prices and previous prices and then the error message shows. it would easier if you downloaded and tested the code.

Comment: When looking at your code there are a number of variables that are not defined.  If these are defined outside the scope of your function then you should add them to the code above.  If they are not defined elsewhere then you should add Option Explicit to the start of each  Module/Class to make sure that all variables have been declared before they are used.

Comment: freeflow, thanks for having a look. I am very limited in vba and it terminology. just to get to this bit took me like forever about 4wks+.  some of what you have said has just gone over my head. I am new to all of this. I'm just blind and lost. As a last resort I came to the forum. hoping some one could help. Thanks again for having a look

Comment: Also, if you don't understand the syntax of a VBA keyword, put the cursor on the Keyword and press F1.  This will bring up the MS Help page for that keyword.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, it is very useful, I have done most of what you advised, very useful, will give RubberDuck a go for sure. I have just updated the main body of the question posted, please see above for more information.

Comment: Is this question still unsolved? If so, can you [edit] to include some test urls that we can copy paste

Comment: QHarr you have just replied to my thread of child elements, this is what I started on. I forgot that this was still live as had gone unanswered since feb. The latest post you have answered to on CANT PULL OFF CHILD ELEMENTS is where I am at now.